# Can't create Win32 textbox to get user input

Tags: c++, winapi

I want to create a textbox where the user inputs some text and clicks OK and the text is acquired in the application code. Here is what I do:

```
HWND handle_textbox = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE, "Edit", message.c_str(), WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_TABSTOP | WS_BORDER | ES_LEFT,
    CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, 200, 24, GetActiveWindow(), (HMENU)(101), (HINSTANCE)GetWindowLong (GetActiveWindow(), GWL_HINSTANCE), NULL);

::ShowWindow(handle_textbox, SW_SHOWDEFAULT);

DWORD err = GetLastError();

char output[512];

GetWindowText(handle_textbox, output, 512);
return std::string(output);
```

But nothing happens and `GetLastError()` returns `0`. No textbox shows up at all?

Comment: Why didn't you check to see if `CreateWindowEx` was successful?

Comment: Do try to make it a bit less random, GetActiveWindow() is a bad idea.  And went wrong when you used GetDlgItem().

Comment: I don't have access to the current HWND, but I am certain it is the active widow. Also what alternative do I have to GetDlgItem?

Comment: Alternative to `GetDltItem`? What about `handle_textbox`? Use the force, Luke.

Comment: Why do you not have access to the main window handle?

Comment: You need a message loop.

Answer (score 3):

The second parameter of CreateWindowEx must be the predefined system class "EDIT". That specifies the type of window you are trying to create.

Then your GetWindowText needs the HWND of the created edit control.

Comment: I did that and updated the code in the description, however the issue still remains the same and GetLastError still returns 0. Am I misisng anything else? No window pops up at all.

Answer (score 1):

The second argument to `CreateWindowEx()` is a *window class*: a string that represents the internal name of a control type. You created one when you opened your main window; this was the string you gave to the `WNDCLASS` structure's `lpszClassName` field.

There are several predefined window classes in user32.dll. [Their names are listed on the MSDN page for `CreateWindowEx()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632680%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), under Remarks.

The name of the text box class is `Edit`, not `Input Text`.

I see you're using the proper edit control styles, so I'm guessing you've found that part of the documentation already. The correct class name is what you were missing.

(Note that window class names are not case-sensitive.)

Comment: Ok it showed up but it looks like it's locked in the parent window and the 'message.c_str()' text is blinking "trough" it and there don't seem to be any controls like the textbox and the ok button.

Comment: Or, simply use the symbolic constant `WC_EDIT`. As an aside, a window class isn't created *"when you open your main window"*. It is registered through a call to [`RegisterClassEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633587.aspx).

Comment: Right; I was referring to the part of the code where he opened his main window, as that was likely where his call to `RegisterClass()` was. (Assuming this is using a common starter template, that is...)

Comment: Yeah I used RegisterClass and it looks dysfunctional - it doesn't show up properly, it's like as if it's on the background but it's tryign to show up in front of the main window.